# MongoDB's mongosniff won't start?

Tags: mongodb

`mongosniff` is for looking at what's sent to the MongoDB server, but on a Mac with OS X Snow Leopard, it says

```
error finding device: no suitable device found
```

this is when `mongod` is running fine.  Is there something that can make it work?

**Update:** thanks.  after running it as root, for some reason it is not reporting any activities when a `mongo` is running with different queries on this same machine.  One time I had an error and it reported once and that was it...  was it to report each activity usually?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running it as root? I get that error when I don't have permission to monitor network traffic.

Edit in response to your update:

You have to specify the network interface to sniff.  Run `ifconfig` to see what your local network name is and then use:

```
sudo mongosniff --source NET lo
```

Comment: A lot of mongosniff issues are pcap related. When I have some time I should find a page that explains all the usual pcap issues (as well as the extra-special winpcap fun) and link to it on the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Running as root works for me:

bobk-mbp:~ bobk$ sudo mongosniff --source NET lo0
  sniffing... 27017
  10.78.4.213:14303  -->> 10.78.4.213:27017 admin.$cmd  58 bytes  id:2447   9287
    query: { ismaster: 1 }  ntoreturn: -1 ntoskip: 0

10.78.4.213:27017  <<--  10.78.4.213:14303   87 bytes  id:2789    10121 - 9287
    reply n:1 cursorId: 0
    { ismaster: true, maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, ok: 1.0 }

...also, ifconfig shows that the LOOPBACK is on lo0 on my system.